# Angular-dart: library pageloader always breaks dependencies in project. How to fix it?

Tags: angular-dart

In more then 3 projects i tried where `pageloader` is included in `pubspec.yaml` error appeared:

- [here](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-1/blob/master/pubspec.yaml)
- [here](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-5)
- [and even here, in official angular example](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples)

for example, in official [hacker_news_pwa](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples/hacker_news_pwa) 
`webdev serve` makes error:

```
webdev could not run for this project.
The `build_runner` version – 1.3.3 – is not within the allowed constraint – >=1.5.0 <2.0.0.
```

when i fix build_ranner version to 1.5.0 another error appears:

```
Because build_runner >=1.1.3 depends on build >=1.0.0 <1.2.0 and pageloader >=3.0.0-beta <3.0.1 depends on build ^0.12.7, build_runner >=1.1.3 is incompatible with pageloader >=3.0.0-beta
  <3.0.1.
And because pageloader >=3.0.0 depends on build_config ^0.3.1 and build_runner >=1.3.4 depends on build_config >=0.4.0 <0.4.1, build_runner >=1.3.4 is incompatible with pageloader
  >=3.0.0-beta.
So, because examples.hacker_news_pwa depends on both pageloader ^3.0.0-beta and build_runner ^1.5.0, version solving failed.
```

and so on and so forth..... endless errors. why?

When `pageloader` is removed errors removes too.

Comment: **There is workaround:**
Angular 5.3.1 still requires webdev 1.0.1. You can install it with this command: `pub global activate webdev 1.0.1.`